# Jquery Accordion tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

How do I default the "Firstpane" set to open and the others are closed....
I copied the same code from this [sample](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/accordion-custom.htm) but on mine everything is open [view here](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/about-phil/team/)

**Script**

```
<script>
$(function() { 

$("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div.pane", {tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', initialIndex: null});
});
</script>

<script>

// add new effect to the tabs
$.tools.tabs.addEffect("slide", function(i, done) {

    // 1. upon hiding, the active pane has a ruby background color
    this.getPanes().slideUp().css({backgroundColor: "#fff"});

    // 2. after a pane is revealed, its background is set to its original color (transparent)
    this.getPanes().eq(i).slideDown(function()  {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor: 'transparent'});

        // the supplied callback must be called after the effect has finished its job
        done.call();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing this fixed my problem **"initialIndex: null"**

Answer (score 0):

or you can put initialIndex: 0 , remember the number you will use, indicate the default pane, 0 is the first element